# How can I fix error syntax when using postman?

Tags: php, mysql, rest, codeigniter

I'm working for REST API for web and using codeigniter.
I have code like this

```
$data = $this->verify_request();
$param = $this->get('param');
$val = $this->get('val');
$operator = $this->db->query("SELECT *FROM `operator` WHERE " . $param . " = '" . $val . "'")->result();
$this->response($operator, 200);
```

In my program i got no error
[image]

but when i'm trying to get it using postman i got error like this
[image]

anyone can help me?

Comment: Unnecessary quotes and space needed in between `*` and `FROM`:- _$operator = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `operator` WHERE $param = $val;")->result();_

Comment: did you pass $param and $val or it blank ?

Comment: Show postman request.

Comment: You should not use codeigniter like this. Parameterize your query. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in getting parameters

```
$val = $this->get('val');
$operator = $this->db->query("SELECT *FROM `operator` WHERE " . $param . " = '" . $val . "'")->result();
```

Try to debug using `var_dump($val)` it's not coming from where you are placing a request. If your value will be there in `$this->get('val');` your issue will be resolved.

`$param = $this->get('param');` also no value in `param`

Your query looks like this.

> SELECT * FROM `operator` WHERE  = ''

No value before and after for comparison. Check your values you passing from form or POSTMAN.